# Encoding problem writing file using nest.js

Tags: node.js, nest, file-writing

We're doing an integration between SAP BTP Document Management Service with a nest.js service to send and download files from repositories.

When I try to download any file, I got an encoding problem in the written file, no matter which encoding I chose (from null to forcing anything else on fs.writeFileSync() ).

Look at the example below, from a PNG image downloaded from BTP DMS:

Good file, downloaded from Postman:

[Good!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pat7.png)

Bad file, downloaded from Node:

[Bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHgJw.png)

Below is the code. We get a file list from a specific folder and download them:

```
const filesAsBinary = []
      for await (const obj of objects) {
        const response = await firstValueFrom(
          this.http.get(sURL + `/${obj}`, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${sJWTTOken}`,
              'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
              responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            },
          }),
        )

        filesAsBinary.push({ filename: obj, content: response })
```

and here, the file writing method:

```
for (const file of allFilesAsBinaryFromFolder) {
      fs.writeFileSync(
        `src/new-accession/documents/email-${folderName}/${file?.filename}`,
        file?.content.data,
      )
    }
```

Any idea in how to properly write those files?

Thanks in advance!

I've tried at least 3 variations of this code - async and sync calls, the result is the same - to conclude the issue is in file writing, not the request itself.